# batch rename multiple files using a string and allowing duplicates

Tags: bash

I am trying to take a single file `prt-dealrpt`, split it up into multiple files, rename the files based on specific strings within the files, and allow for duplicates with (1), (2), etc at the end of the file name.

Here is a portion of the file:

```
Vendor: GREAT LAKES                 Buyer - Melissa         APU/DND
        Begin Date:  10/16/2017 
        End Date:    12/08/2017

Vendor: SENECA                      Buyer - Bill            This is a note
        Begin Date:  10/16/2017
        End Date:    12/08/2017

Vendor: MC-CAIN                     Buyer - Bill            APU/DND
        Begin Date:  10/16/2017
        End Date:    12/08/2017

Vendor: MC-CAIN                     Buyer - Ethan           APU\DND
        Begin Date:  10/16/2017
        End Date:    12/08/2017
```

**EDIT:** The file above has more following the vendor name on the same line. Most of the files will not rename because it is looking for AUP/DND directories. The ones that do rename are actually renaming to the last part of the line, so in this example the new name of the vendor `SENECA` would be `This is a note.dat`

I need to split the file at every use of the word `Vendor`
I am successfully doing this with a shell named `split.sh`

```
csplit --prefix page --suffix-format %02d.dat prt-dealrpt '/^Vendor/' '{*}'
```

This creates files called `page00.dat` `page001.dat` `page02.dat` and so on.

Next I am trying to rename the files to the vendor name. I am doing this with a batch file called `fixname.bat`

```
@echo off

for %%i in ("C:\Users\waker\Documents\Unipro\Vendor\*.dat") do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%j in ('findstr /B "Vendor" "%%i"') do (
    ren "%%i" "%%j.temp_dat"
  )
)

ren *.temp_dat *.dat
```

This works however it does not allow for duplicates. It will skip over the files where a duplicate name would be created. Using the example above I would be left with `GREAT LAKES.dat` `SENECA.dat` `MC-CAIN.dat` and `page03.dat`. I would like the duplicate to be named `MC-CAIN(2).dat`

Any help would be appreciated, also if anyone has suggestions to do this all with one button instead of running two separate commands.

I am running windows 10 with "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put something like the following in to a bash script and execute it in the directory with your page*.dat files:

```
newext="temp_dat"
for i in page*.dat;
do
        filename=$(grep 'Vendor' $i|sed 's/^.*Vendor:\ *\(..*\) *Buyer.*/\1/;s/\ *$//');
        if [[ $filename == '' ]]; then
                echo "Skipping file $i with no Vendor"
                continue;
        fi
        dstfile="${filename}.${newext}"
        if [[ -e "$dstfile" ]]; then
                dstfile="${filename} (1).${newext}";
                if [[ -e "$dstfile" ]]; then
                        lastfilenum=$(ls -1 "${filename} ("*").${newext}"|sort|tail -1|sed "s/^.* (\(.*\)).*/\1/")
                        nextfilenum=$(expr $lastfilenum + 1)
                        dstfile="${filename} (${nextfilenum}).${newext}"
                fi
        fi;
        mv "$i" "$dstfile"
done
```

I am assumming Windows bash comes with the standard gnu tools available in Linux such as: grep, sort, tail, and sed.

When I ran it on my Linux machine I got the following results with the above code in script.sh:

```
[sudarsha@callisto so]$ ls
page00.dat  page02.dat  page04.dat   script.sh
page01.dat  page03.dat  prt-dealrpt
[sudarsha@callisto so]$ ./script.sh
Skipping file page00.dat with no Vendor
[sudarsha@callisto so]$ ls -1
GREAT LAKES.temp_dat
MC-CAIN (1).temp_dat
MC-CAIN.temp_dat
page00.dat
prt-dealrpt
script.sh
SENECA.temp_dat
[sudarsha@callisto so]$
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I saved this to fixname.sh and placed it in the directory with my page*.dat files. When I try to run it from Bash I get 

./fixname.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/fixname.sh: line 2: `for i in page*.dat;

Comment: I think that is because of the windows txt files require carriage return automatically placed in the file if you use an editor like notepad to create it.  You may want to try another editor like notepad++ to edit bash scripts. 
Try the following command to remove the carriage return characters from the file and create fixname2.sh: `cat fixname.sh | sed 's/\r$//' > fixname2.sh`

Comment: Thank you, removing the carriage returns worked. The script ran but with errors. See the edit above, I didn't include all of the information from the original prt-dealrpt file, I have added more above.

Comment: I will edit my answer to fix the script.  Essentially, you have to change the regular expression used with the `sed` command to extract the file name from the line.

Comment: This worked perfectly as expected! Out of the few hundred files all but 10 were renamed. The ones that were not, I didn't realize until now, have a / in the vendor name, example `BERRY GLOBAL/AEP`. Is there a way to ignore slashes between the `Vendor:` and `Buyer`? If not I can rename the 10 files manually.

Comment: Yes.  You can replace the filename like like this: `filename=$(grep 'Vendor' $i|sed 's/^.*Vendor:\ *\(..*\) *Buyer.*/\1/;s/\ *$//;s/\// /g');` The last part replaces all / in the file name with spaces.